# Constructors Which Create Constructors (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

In a simulation I'm making, I'll have an Element class, which I'll call with params about the properties of that Element (melting and boiling temperatures, rules for reactions with other Elements, color, density, etc.) to create the basic types of Elements (water, oxygen, carbon, etc.). From these, I simply would like to create new "Atoms" from the water, oxygen, and carbon templates I would have. I'm wondering if there's a way to use a constructor (Element) to create a new constructor (like Water)? For example, I would like to be able to do something like this.

```
var Element = function(/* params */) {
    // common element properties and basic functions
}
var Water = new Element(); // create the new element
var WaterAtom = new Water(); // create the atom (an instance of the element)
// draw the atom, manipulate it, react with other atoms, etc.
```

I'm basically asking, can a constructor create another constructor? I would like it this way so I don't have to create tons and tons of `.prototype` code that extends the basic Element class.

Comment: What is this supposed to accomplish? Where do you specify new behavior for the `Water` class?

Comment: No, a *constructor*  can't create another constructor, you should consider it to be a simple constructor-producing *function* that is not invoked with `new`.

Comment: Are these things supposed to be subclasses of `Element`? Then `Element` is a constructor that constructs element instances - not constructors.

Comment: Btw, I think you mean `Hydrogen` not `Water`.

Comment: Aren't you simply asking about JavaScript inheritance here?

Comment: @Bergi I think you're right, I should make it a function which _produces_ constructors, and BTW, in terms of my simulation, Water can be an element because it is the smallest unit in the program. Nobody says that it has to be exactly like real life.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I am, but I don't want to write tons of `this extends that` and `this.prototype.that` and all of that. I just want it to create the "class" where I tell it "when water reacts with fire, put out the fire" or "when water gets hot, turn it into vapor", and after that I'll just create new instances of that "class".

Comment: @SimpleJ I'll specify the behaviors for Water in one of its params called `rules`, which is basically a function which is called every time the frame updates and describes its reactions, movement, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
function Element(…) {
    // init properties that all elements share
}
Element.prototype.… = function(…) { … }; // add all methods of elements

Element.makeType = function(rules) {
    function ElementType(…) {
        Element.call(this, …);
    }
    ElementType.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);
    ElementType.prototype.constructor = ElementType;
    ElementType.prototype.rules = rules;
    return ElementType;
};
```

so that you can use it like

```
var Water = Element.makeType(function(…) {
    // do whatever makes water special
});

var drop = new Water(…);
```

Comment: Nice! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a utility function for generating subclasses of `Element`:

```
function Element() {}

function subElement() {
  function SubElement() {}
  SubElement.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);
  return SubElement;
}

var Water = subElement();
var waterAtom = new Water();
```

Comment: `Object.create(Element);` - nope.

Comment: @SimpleJ Hmm... I'll try it.

Comment: @Bergi Woops. I guess I've become too use to the class syntax